# how to get index inside object on array to make it new obejct based on longest index

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array like this:

```
arrays = [
 {"y":"2020","OVO":3},
 {"y":"2021","OVO":2,"Dana":1},
 {"y":"2019","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":3},
 {"y":"2018","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":4,"Gopay":1}, //length = 5
 {"y":"2022","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":1}
];
```

now i want to create new array based on longest object key from arrays.
should from this:

```
{"y":"2018","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":4,"Gopay":1}, //length = 5
```

to this :

```
['OVO','Dana','Shopepay','Gopay']
```

how to achieve that in javascript?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your attempted code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```js
const arrays = [
 {"y":"2020","OVO":3},
 {"y":"2021","OVO":2,"Dana":1},
 {"y":"2019","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":3},
 {"y":"2018","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":4,"Gopay":1},
 {"y":"2022","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":1}
];
const longestArray = arrays.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length)?.pop(); // sort for most object with most properties

console.log(Object.keys(longestArray).slice(1)); // remove first element from array
```

Or as simple one-liner:

```
Object.keys(arrays.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length)?.pop()).slice(1);
```

Comment: yeah u save me. its very simple and crystal clear. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve your goal

```js
arrays = [
 {"y":"2020","OVO":3},
 {"y":"2021","OVO":2,"Dana":1},
 {"y":"2019","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":3},
 {"y":"2018","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":4,"Gopay":1}, //length = 5
 {"y":"2022","OVO":2,"Dana":1,"Shopepay":1}
];

const max = arrays.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.length > Object.keys(current).length) ? prev : Object.keys(current)).splice(1)

console.log(max)
```

Comment: thanks dude. but i think u forget to .slice() "y"
but still its very clear.

Comment: I updated the example with `splice` :)